# locking some parts of a php file for guaranteed execution

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency

Suppose I have a php file named test.php. Some parts of the test.php is as follows:

```
if($val==4)
{
        $sql = "UPDATE `$tbln` SET noc='".substr($targetPath,3)."' WHERE $pri=$uploadID;";
        $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        $sql="DELETE FROM `$tbln` WHERE noc IS NULL;";
        mysqli_query($db,$sql);
}

elseif($val==5)
{
        $sql = "UPDATE `$tbln` SET circular='".substr($targetPath,3)."' WHERE $pri=$uploadID;";
        $result=mysqli_query($db,$sql);
        $sql="DELETE FROM `$tbln` WHERE circular IS NULL;";
        mysqli_query($db,$sql);
}
```

test.php is frequently called from another php file. Is there any way to lock the 
if block or elseif block so that test.php can only be executed after  the completion of the if/ elseif block of the previous call?

Comment: Not your issue, BUT you should parameterize your queries.

Comment: @user3783243 depends if any of those various variables came from user input or not. Needless preparing is needless. Plus you cannot parameterize table or field names like he is doing.

Comment: *"Is there any way to lock the if block or elseif block so that test.php can only be executed after the completion of the if/ elseif block of the previous call?"* ... Why? The database row should lock anyway when it's being updated.

Answer (score -1):

Not sure if I do understand your problem correctly but I would suggest do simply add an

`else{ exit(); }`

to stop your PHP script.
You can also add an error code as described in the [PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exit.php).